# Cast from 'Result<AnyObject>' to unrelated type 'NSArray' always fails

Tags: swift, swift2, alamofire

The following code was working ok on XCode 6/Swift 1, but gives me an error on XCode 7/Swift 2

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(self.REQ_URL)", parameters: parameters).validate(contentType: ["application/json"]).responseJSON(options: [], completionHandler: { (req, resp, data) -> Void in

        let data_ar = data as! NSArray //here I get the error 

        })
```

The error I get is

> Cast from 'Result' to unrelated type 'NSArray' always fails

How am I supposed to use the returned JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the syntax has changed, and the following works

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(self.REQ_URL)", parameters: parameters)
    .responseJSON { request, response, result in
        switch result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let data_ar = data as! NSArray

        case .Failure(let data, let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

just in case of you are using swiftyjson for xcode 7 branch,

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(self.REQ_URL)", parameters: parameters)
.responseJSON { request, response, result in
    switch result {
    case .Success(let data):
        let json = JSON(data)
        let something = json["aaa"].string
        ....

    case .Failure(let data, let error):
        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
```